# socket.io only connection with IP Address on iPad

Tags: ipad, websocket, socket.io

I'm having a weird issue with the ipad and socket.io. I can connect without issues on a computer with a host entry or an IP address. I'm doing a simple connect as seen below:

```
var socketUri = 'http://rpi-scale-2.com';
socket = io.connect(socketUri);
```

The `socketUri` is a locally qualified domain. This connection happens and is successful on the desktop and windows tablets. It however isn't successful on an iPad regardless of browser. If we change the `socketUri` to an IP Address the iPad works great.

Can anyone give me any tips what might be causing the issues on the iPad?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue if the domain name doesn't work, but the IP address does.

Comment: DNS works for all other browser/machine combos though

Comment: I'm just saying that the ONLY difference between connecting to a named server vs. connecting to an IP address is DNS since it is the job of DNS to turn a named host into an IP address which can then be connected to.  Could there be a DNS cache on the iPad with old data in it?  Have you changed the IP address in DNS for rpi-scale-2.com recently?

Comment: I don't know what tools are easily available on the iPad, but you could try to find out what IP address the iPad thinks http://rpi-scale-2.com is at and see if it's correct.